# How to get Time-of-Flight information from GPS in Android

Tags: android, gps

Is it possible to get the ToF information from the `GPS API` in an **Android** environment ?

There are some info about the satellites but I can't find anything about time of flight.

```
GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
if(gpsStatus != null) {
    Iterable<GpsSatellite>satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
    Iterator<GpsSatellite>sat = satellites.iterator();
    //HOW TO GET TIME OF FLIGHT ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it supports you with latitude, longitude, altitude, accuracy, time, speed and there's nothing about ToF.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I get these information? Maybe the time info has may help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, Time-Of-Flight is not a GPS parameter.
There might be special devices like 3d-cameras that use the GPS clock for Time-of-flight measures, but this then is a special device.

A  GPS (GNSS) chip does not have Time-Of-Flight.

And neither ios nor andorid (therefore) has it.